# Cancel button not showing up in UINavigationController in modal for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to add a cancel button for the  modal in the navigation bar for iPad.

I'm using the following code:

```
    UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:abPersonController];
    navController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                          target:self
                                                                                          action:@selector(dismissModal)];
    [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

For some reason though, the cancel button does not show up.

Using spark inspector, I'm seeing a back indicator where the cancel button is supposed to be but it is hidden, and when you run it in on iPad Simulator, you cannot see the cancel button or the back indicator.

I tried setting the back indicator's hidden property to NO but nothing shows up.

Edit: The only way I can get it to work is if I add the button in the completion block:

```
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:^{abPersonController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = doneButton;}];
```

But this solution looks bad because the done button pops in after the modal has already been on screen. Are there any other ways to get it so it doesn't have to be in the completion block?

Edit:

```
        UIViewController *dummyView = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:dummyView];
        [navController pushViewController:abPersonController animated:NO];
        abPersonController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
        abPersonController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                              target:self
                                                                                              action:@selector(dismissModal)];
        navController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
        navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
        [self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
        navController.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
```

Comment: You need to apply the button to the `navigationItem` of the view controller you put in the nav controller, not to the nav controller itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be backBarButtomItem instead of leftBarButtomItem.

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:abPersonController];
navController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                      target:self
                                                                                      action:@selector(dismissModal)];
[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: fyi: this answer is messed up

Answer (score 0):

How about:

## 1.

```
navController.navigationBar.topItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                                      target:self
                                                                                                      action:@selector(dismissModal)];
```

---

## 2.

```
abPersonController.navigationItem.lefBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                                   target:self
                                                                                                   action:@selector(dismissModal)];
```

---

### Or...

In `abPersonController` object's class `-viewDidLoad` (or *`init`*) you can do:

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButton:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel
                                                                                    target:self
                                                                                    action:@selector(dismissModal)]];
```

Comment: Or simply `abPersonController.navigationItem.lefBarButtonItem = ...`

Comment: @rmaddy : yes, that too. (_will include that in the answer now_) thanks

Comment: I tried 1 and 2, and neither of them work. I'll attach a view hierarchy to my main question.

Comment: @codenamepenryn : hm... not even in `abPersonController`'s `-viewDidLoad`?

Comment: abPersonController is made by Apple so I only have access to the h file.

Comment: @codenamepenryn : then try the second method `abPersonController.navigationItem.lefBarButtonItem = ...` (_as suggested by rmaddy_)

Comment: For some reason, I have to add the left button in the completion block in the presentViewController for it to show up.

Comment: @codenamepenryn : maybe the `abPersonController` object has it's own `navigationController` (_since it's an object of Apple's class but not sure_)

Comment: I think I found a solution to the problem, I posted a link in the original question. I have a question about the found solution which I also posted in the original question, can someone clarify the solution for me please?

Comment: @codenamepenryn : [Apple Docs on ABPersonViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) state `The ABPersonViewController class does not support subclassing` (_anyways, i haven't meddled with this class so i can't really say much_)

Comment: Oh, so do you know what he means by "Override ABPersonViewController (DisplayContactViewController below) so you can implement viewDidDisappear." then?

Comment: I think ABPersonViewController doesn't allow subclassing in iOS 7 and above so I don't think the solution works anymore.

Comment: @codenamepenryn : i think what's going on there is... **1**. Create a dummy `UIViewController` (that they named `parentController`) **2**. make `parentController` the `rootViewController` of the `navigationController` **3**. Push `ABPersonViewController` onto the `navigationController` stack **4**. present the `navigationController` (_all this so that `ABPersonViewController` doesn't do what it's doing to you right now_)

Comment: Ok, so I did that, now there is a back button that appears. I can hide it, but I cannot replace it with a cancel button. I updated the main post with the updated code.

Comment: Nvm, got it to work! I was setting leftBarButtonItem and not backBarButtonItem. Thanks!

Comment: @codenamepenryn : no probs but this answer would have worked if it weren't for `ABPersonViewController` (_i'm guessing :P_) anyways...  accept your own answer :)